# Code Coverage Tool That Supports Annotation of JUnit Tests To Specify Which Method The UnitTest Covers

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, metrics

I'm looking for something like PHPUnit's "[Specifying Covered Methods](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.specifying-covered-methods)" for Java. That means a code coverage tool that comes with annotations for my JUnit tests so that I can specify which method is tested by which JUnit test.

The effect of this would be much more correct metrics on covered lines, because only the lines of the specified method are counted and and not all executed lines of the whole application.

Answer (score 2):

This approach sounds as if it would place a heavy burden on the programmer. It either assumes a 1:1 correspondence between a test and a method (which goes against the usual advice to think in terms of testing the behaviour of a class, not methods) or requires to programmer to manually track the route through private methods etc for each entry point as the code is refactored and changed over time.

It's difficult to see how this could be implemented with type safety - quick automated operations such as method renames would require a manual step to update the annotations in the tests.

If your requirement is to gain a more accurate estimate of the effectiveness of your test suite, an alternative approach you might consider is mutation testing. This seeds faults into your code then checks if your suite is able to detect them.

There are a number of systems available for Java including

- http://pitest.org
- http://jumble.sourceforge.net/
- https://github.com/david-schuler/javalanche/

A comparison of them is available here

http://pitest.org/java_mutation_testing_systems/